# How to set checkbox component checked in Material-UI React?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

As the title,
I want to set checkbox "checked" by default when the page was fully load,
but in the tutorial about [Material-UI Checkbox component](https://material-ui.com/api/checkbox/),
didn't have the `defaultChecked` props.
When I add `checked={true}` props, then get arror
like 
"A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type checkbox to be controlled...etc"
How should I do?

there is my code
I want to list all the group, include the default group and the other
let the user to choose multi group.

```
  export default class AcceptButton extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    this.state = {open: true}
  }
  handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({checked: event.target.checked})
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
       <div>
         group : 
       </div>
       <div className="f-col">
       {
        group.data.map(g => {
          if (data.filter(d => d.gid == g.gid).length != 0) {
            return (
              <FormControlLabel
                key={g.gid}
                control={
                  <Checkbox
                    disabled={true}
                    onChange = {this.handleChange}
                    color="primary"
                    checked={this.state.open}
                  />
                }
                label={g.gname}
              />
          )}
          else {
            return (
              <FormControlLabel
                key={g.gid}
                control={
                  <Checkbox
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                    value={g.gname}
                    color="primary"
                  />
                }
                label={g.gname}
              />
          )}
        })
      }
    </div> 
    <button className="btn" onClick={this.postassignhandle}>update</button>
  </Fragment>
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made checkboxstate a maps type

```
const checkboxstatemap = new Map()
export default class AcceptButton extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)

    this.state = {checkboxstate: group.data.map((item) =>  checkboxstatemap.set(item.gid, true ))}
}

componentDidMount() {
handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({checked: event.target.checked})
}
render() {
    return (
    <Fragment>
    <div>
        group : 
    </div>
    <div className="f-col">
    {
        group.data.map(g => {
        if (data.filter(d => d.gid == g.gid).length != 0) {
            return (
            <FormControlLabel
                key={g.gid}
                control={
                <Checkbox
                    disabled={true}
                    onChange = {this.handleChange}
                    color="primary"
                    checked={this.state.checkboxstate.get(g.gid)}
                />
                }
                label={g.gname}
            />
        )}
        else {
            return (
            <FormControlLabel
                key={g.gid}
                control={
                <Checkbox
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                    value={g.gname}
                    color="primary"
                />
                }
                label={g.gname}
            />
        )}
        })
    }
    </div> 
    <button className="btn" onClick={this.postassignhandle}>update</button>
</Fragment>
)
```

Comment: But I can't know how many checkbox should have.
So set state to all checkbox can't work I think.

Comment: @honeytoast is your `gid ` field sequential ?

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Answer (score 12):

it does have a **defaultChecked** props and you can use it like :

```
<Checkbox defaultChecked={true} 
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          color="primary"
 />
```

Comment: I tried this but then React gives me a warning:
`Warning: ForwardRef(SwitchBase) contains an input of type checkbox with both checked and defaultChecked props. Input elements must be either controlled or uncontrolled (specify either the checked prop, or the defaultChecked prop, but not both). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element and remove one of these props.`

Comment: @TommiL. yeah right , probably when you use defaultChecked prop ,checked prop is not necessarily to use and using defaultChecked and checked props at same time has a Intervening for React to manage the checkbox , so you should remove one of them , Thank you for your comment

Comment: I wonder why this prop doesn't appear on the Checkbox documentation.

Comment: Using `defaultChecked` instead of passing a value to `checked` results in error: `MUI: A component is changing the default checked state of an uncontrolled SwitchBase after being initialized`.

Answer (score 1):

```
import React from 'react';
import Checkbox from '@material-ui/core/Checkbox';

class Checkboxes extends React.Component {
  state = {
    checkedBox: true,
  };

  handleChange = name => event => {
    this.setState({ [name]: event.target.checked });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Checkbox
          checked={this.state.checkedBox}
          onChange={this.handleChange('checkedBox')}
          value="checkedBox"
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Try this.

Answer (score 1):

```
import React, { useCallback, useState } from 'react';
import { Checkbox, FormControlLabel } from '@material-ui/core';

const defaultProps = {
    margin: 'normal',
    onChange: (e) => {}
};
const InputCheckbox = (props) => {
    const { onChange, label, value=false, name, checkedIcon, icon, className, style } = props;

    const [ isChecked, setChecked ] = useState(value);
    const _onChange = useCallback(
        (e) => {
            setChecked((value) => {
                onChange(e, { [e.target.name]: !value });
                return !value;
            });
        },
        [ onChange ]
    );
    return <FormControlLabel className={className} style={style} label={label} control={<Checkbox name={name} icon={icon} checkedIcon={checkedIcon} checked={isChecked} onChange={_onChange} />} />;
};
InputCheckbox.defaultProps = defaultProps;
export default InputCheckbox;
```

use onChange to callback value and use value to do initialize

Answer (score 0):

youst must add attribute checked inc component, sometimes use value but don`t work always use checked attribute.

```
<Checkbox onChange={this.handleChange}
          color="primary"
          checked={this.state.checked}
 />
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: sometimes use value but don`t work always use checked attribute can you explain ?

Comment: yeah, use checked is de functional mode then value don't work